# Do meshes have to be connected?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender and I was wondering, do meshes have to be joined?

In the image below, I found it a lot easier to just snap the edges to the top face instead of joining all the vertexes. Is that a correct way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Your approach to connectedness is fine for your solid objects example today.  Especially true if the object is not animated and not bending.  Your use probably will not run into problems for the activities of your project. (Just a informal guess, since those activities are not specified above)  If you were to animate a organic face with an armature for closeups ... then a whole different set of standards might apply.

Comment: Just make sure you know how to extrude faces of a mesh. You should be able to make a choice to save you time and energy.  At some point you may find the extrude operation easier in some cases.  Plenty of videos on the site with the name that rhymes with noonoob address extrusion and snapping.

Comment: I see, thank you so much! I'll do some more research on extrusion, so I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: Text to mesh conversion can result in meshes of multiple pieces.  Fluid simulations .  And then there is the monkey ...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your use-case, but in general, no, it's not necessary for meshes to be connected. A good rule of thumb is that if the object is composed of separate parts in real life, it's okay for its model to be made of separate parts.